# js requests to Rails 6.0 app render html template instead of js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-upgrade

I'm in the process of migrating a legacy Rails 5.0 app to (hopefully) 7.x. I got to 5.2.x without too much trouble. I'm currently trying to upgrade to 6.0 and I have a problem with controller actions that are set up to render either js or html depending on the type of request. For example, in a standard 'new' action of the general form:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

if a jQuery ajax request is sent with `dataType: 'script'`, the server renders the `views/posts/new.html.erb` template instead of `views/posts/new.js.coffee`. The console confirms that the request is received as a js request but that html is being rendered, e.g.

```
Started GET "/posts/new" for 127.0.0.1
Processing by PostsController#new as JS
  Rendering posts/new.html.erb
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb
```

However, if I remove new.html.erb from the view directory, then the server renders the js template as required.

```
Started GET "/posts/new" for 127.0.0.1
Processing by PostsController#new as JS
  Rendering posts/new.js.coffee
  Rendered posts/new.js.coffee
```

I'm seeing the same behavior with a number of different controllers/actions.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing? FWIW, I am not using webpacker, just regular sprockets. And ruby 2.6.6. The only thing I've changed from 5.2.x related to javascript is to add an `assets/config/manifest.js` file with the following:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

Edit:
Also FWIW, I added a block with a test statement to the #js and #html methods -

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {puts "calling js"}
    format.html {puts "calling html"}
  end
```

and confirmed that the #js method is the one that's being called, even though it is rendering the html template.

Comment: does `new.js.erb` work instead of .coffee?

Comment: Ah, yes! `new.js.erb` does work! So apparently Rails 6 does not handle coffeescript automatically. I can't see anything in the release notes for 5.0, 5.1, 5.2 or 6.0 to indicate that this was changed. What is the appropriate way to get coffeescript compiled under Rails 6? I tried downgraded sprockets from 4.2.1 to 3.7.2, the last version I had before upgrading to Rails 6, but that hasn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going too deep, this bit here is an issue:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/actionview/lib/action_view/path_set.rb#L48*

```rb
def find(*args)
  find_all(*args).first || raise(MissingTemplate.new(self, *args))
  #              ^^^^^^
end
# where `find_all` returns
# =>
# [
#   #<ActionView::Template app/views/posts/new.html.erb locals=[]>,
#   #<ActionView::Template app/views/posts/new.js.coffee locals=[]>
# ]
```

`html` format is added along the way as a fallback for `js`:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0/actionview/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb#L291-L294*

```rb
if values == [:js]
  values << :html
  @html_fallback_for_js = true
end
```

This is definitely a rails bug. I'm not exactly sure when it was fixed but everything works fine in `rails v7`.

---

If you're planning on upgrading, try some later rails 6 versions, see if they fixed it back then. For now I can think of a couple of solutions:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render formats: :js } # explicitly render js format only
  format.html
end
```

Other than that, you could override `find_all` method and fix the order of templates to correspond to the order of formats - `[:js, :html]`:

```rb
# config/initializers/render_coffee_fix.rb

module RenderCoffeeFix
  def find_all(path, prefixes = [], *args)
    templates = super
    _, options = args

    ordered_templates = options[:formats].map do |format|
      templates.detect { |template| template.format == format }
    end.compact

    ordered_templates
  end
end

ActionView::PathSet.prepend(RenderCoffeeFix)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly set the `accepts` header in your JQuery ajax request.  Since you have templates for both formats.  I believe Rails is favoring the HTML format, so long as the request deems it acceptable.

Comment: Also, I believe the `respond_to` block in your action is no longer necessary, since you are using the default behavior of rendering a template named after the action.  

In other words, Rails will respect the desired response type, so long as there is a matching template available.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried doing that but without success. The browser debugging window indicates that without specifying the `accepts` header explicitly, the header is `text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01`.  When I do specify it, e.g. `text/javascript`, in the `jQuery.ajax` function using the documented syntax, the debugger confirms that that is being applied. However the response behavior is unchanged.